# Object Appering in preview mode but not in renders

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, tracking

I'm Trying to render a box on top of a video that ive tracked in the 3D viewport everything looks fine but when I render the frame using f12 the geometry is missing from the rendered image.

[image: Preview Render]

[image: Output Render]

I'm Pretty new to blender especially 2.8 so if there is anything missing please ask me and im going to put it in the post.

Comment: In the Outliner (in the top-right of the screen, in the default workspace), is the "Disable in Renders" icon (a little camera) next to the cube Enabled or Disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment above, you should first check if the Disable in Renders toggle is Enabled or Disabled. You can find this in the Outliner, which will appear in this area (circled in red) of the default workspace:

[image]

If the Disable in Renders toggle indicates that the object should be rendered, then the problem may be more complicated. This seems like the most likely problem, though.

Comment: I've checked thatand everything in the Outliner sould be rendered. But I Just realized that the cube is transparent for some reason.